# Android SharedPreferences is reset to default values. After restarting app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, sharedpreferences, default

Sometimes after restarting the app resets the sharedpreferences on devices with API level > 13. 
The sharedpreferences are set at the beginning of the app (first activity of the app).

code:

```
Public void saveCountry(Context context, String countryCode) {

   SharedPreferences settingsActivity  = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settingsActivity.edit();
   editor.putString("key_country", countryCode);
   editor.commit();

   setDefaultChannels(context);
}

public String getCountry(Context mContext) {

   SharedPreferences settingsActivity  = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   String country = settingsActivity.getString("key_country", null);
   return country;
}
```

I dont know what im doing wrong and why it is happening. I noticed this specially after receiving a push-notification to a detailactivity.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the saving methods at the beginning of your app like this?

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    saveCountry();
```

Because if you are, you are calling it every time at startup, so the country will be overridden with whatever data `countryCode` equals at startup, which could be nothing. So maybe you should have some code that only calls that on first run.

Here is how I have it implemented in my app.

```
    boolean firstRun;
    final SharedPreferences firstRunPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    firstRun = firstRunPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true);

    if(firstRun==true){

    saveCountry();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = firstRunPref.edit();
        editor3.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
        editor3.commit(); 
    }
```